# How to use Atata for just a basic auto browser detect and then auto driver setup? I'm reading the documentation and not having much luck making sense

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, atata

Does anyone have any experience using atata at all? Someone recommended I use it for setting up a chrome driver automatically. I'm looking for the most basic way to detect what chrome version the user has and then set up the driver according to their local installed browser version when the program runs. Any help would be appreciated. Question is in the title.

Here are the links to it:

https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-webdriversetup
https://atata.io/

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Set Up Version Corresponding to Locally Installed Browser Version](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-webdriversetup#set-up-version-corresponding-to-locally-installed-browser-version) section it is:

```
DriverSetup.AutoSetUp(BrowserNames.Chrome);
```

Comment: but im a bit confused, do I first have to instantiate a new chrome driver of my own?              Does it configure the drivers i have in my script automatically or do I have to feed in the drivers somewhere? If not, is there a way I can manually feed specific drivers that I want configured according to the AutoSetUp Method?

Comment: Please check the documentation link above. The recommended place to perform driver(s) setup is a global set up method. After `DriverSetup` actions, you can just instantiate and use a corresponding WebDriver class, like `ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();`.

Comment: I did check the documentation, it told me to use the global setup method and yes it showed there's an instantiation of a ChromeDriver but it didn't say whether that chrome driver automatically recieves the configurations when you call DriverSetup? Also, if it does, when you use the DriverSetup does it configure all instantiated drivers in the project or only on the same file/cs file as the DriverSetup method?

Comment: `DriverSetup` just downloads an appropriate driver executable file, e.g. `chromedriver.exe`. Then adds the driver path to environment "PATH" variable, which is consumed by WebDriver classes, e.g. `ChromeDriver`.